# Limit execution time of system() call in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have a program which makes use of an external .exe that accepts text files as command inputs. I'm making a call such as this:

```
system("xfoil.exe < create_results.txt > nul");
```

That executes the program "xfoil" with the correct parameters that I write in the create_results.txt file.

The problem is sometimes the execution does not converge and enters an infinite loop, so I need a way to stop the execution of the system() call after it exceeds a set time.

If I am not mistaken I should use some kind of threading to do this, the problem is I cannot change the program, so I cant send signals while it's executing to check if it has entered an infinite loop. The only way I can think of is a timeout, but I have not found how to execute a thread for x amount of time and then kill it (in c++) without producing leaks.

I'm doing this in windows, C++11

Comment: Do not use `system`. It looks it might be easy, but it's **very** limited in its interface. Use your system's api instead (fork/exec on posix systems, CreateProcess on windows).

Comment: I guess you should not use `system` but the lower, Windows specific, primitives to start a process, perhaps [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614263/c-timeout-for-an-external-application-call and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992677/system-call-time-out

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks for the answers and sorry for the duplicate. Should have looked better.